# Wait until Upload completes

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to upload a larger file (size > 2MB) using puppeteer and the upload takes more than a couple of minutes to complete (5 - 6 minutes). I tried to handle the wait using the below methods after the 'Upload' button click, however, they exit with timeout exceeded error.

1. `page.waitForSelector(<id>)` - After successful upload, a label appears which I'm trying to capture to identify the upload is successful.
2. `page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("<id>")');` - which again returns timeout exceeded error; and
3. `page.waitForNavigation( { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });` which again return the same.

I tried altering the default timeout which worked, however couldn't appreciate it as an ideal workaround.

Am I missing something here.

---

Comment: You approaches are correct and they work if you increase the timeout (as you did). I don't believe there's another solution, only to get a faster connection :)

Comment: @Shamees hey how did you solve this? Facing the same issue

Comment: @s.khan you could increase the default timeout; or if you have a label/selector that appears post upload process, you may wait for the same to determine a successful upload. These are only workarounds.

Comment: @ShameesIbnYousaf thanks mate. There was no other way but to increase the default timeout.